# How to install cvxopt on on windows 10 on python 3.6

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, python-3.6, conda, cvxopt

How do I install cvxopt on windows 10 on python 3.6?

When running

```
conda install cvxopt

Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - cvxopt -> python 3.5*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I apologize i am on windows...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found that we need to install both the numpy+mkl package and the appropriate cvxopt from:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Download the file, then do the following:

1) in a command line go to the downloads folder

2) pip install "numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

3) pip install "cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

Comment: On step 3) pip install "pip install "cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
change to: pip install "cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

Answer (score 0):

The library can be installed directly using `pip`

```
(qiskit) C:\Python37>pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall cvxopt
```

It downloads the below wheels

```
cvxopt-1.2.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (822 kB)
mkl-2019.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (224.1 MB)

Successfully installed cvxopt-1.2.5 intel-openmp-2019.0 mkl-2019.0
```

You may have to set the Python path as well in the environment variable to get it working!